# C# Split() function is not working

Tags: c#, linq

Hello I am new to c# in fact fairly new to programming, I am having issues with the split function. I am trying to split a single string from a textbox to multiple strings.

I am getting the following error:

> CS1061    'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no
>   extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I have done the following:
* checked to see that system.core dll is added as a reference
*checked using system.Linq is on the program
*checked target framework which is 4.0

I am having no luck solving this issue.

Code with error:

```
string[] sampNumStrings = new string[] { textBoxBarcode.Text };
string[] newSampNumStrings = sampNumStrings.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: `Split()` is used for a single string, not for an array of strings as you're attempting to do.

Comment: You need to include your code in the post, not a screenshot. Anyway, you're calling `.split()` on an `array` of strings, not a `string`.

Comment: A textbox wouldn't return an array of strings either, it returns a string, so how are you getting an array?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input, all of the answers were very helpful. I figured It will be something that I overlooked, but that is part of the learning process I guess. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `sampNumStrings` as an ***array*** of strings, that's what the `[]` means in `string[]`. Arrays do not have a `Split()` method. You should be doing it like this:

```
string sampNumStrings = textBoxBarcode.Text;
string[] newSampNumStrings = sampNumStrings.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Or better yet, in one line:

```
string[] newSampNumStrings = textBoxBarcode.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cause there is no method for string array. Split method is for String type.

```
string source = "[stop]ONE[stop][stop]TWO[stop][stop][stop]THREE[stop][stop]";
string[] result = source.Split(new string[] {"[stop]"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_

Answer (score 1):

string[] is an array so it's not support Split() method.
Replace string[] with string if you get string from only 1 textbox.
Example:
string samNumString = txtBarCode.Text;
string[] newNumStrings = samNumString.Split(....);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split array of strings based on specific split options you can do something like below:

```
 string[] sampNumStrings = new string[] { "Test String", "Test String1", "Test String 2" };
 string[][] newSampNumStrings = sampNumStrings.Select(var=>var.Split(new string[] { " ", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)).ToArray();
```

Like as others said you can perform Split operation only on a String and Arrays do not support split operation